# VS code cannot read java file

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I am running java spring boot in `VSCode IDE` , but if I edit something while running `VSCode` give an error "`Unresolved compilation[Screenshot of the error][1]`".

I think the IDE cannot read the java file after modification.

Someone can tell me why is it happening ? [1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw3s8.png][1]

Comment: Please provide more information like code/configuration examples and screenshots

Comment: I already updated the question @ConstantinBeer , I add some screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague but it sounds like you haven't installed the necessary plugins. Here's the documentation for setting up VS Code for Java.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java

UPDATE:
Looking at the screenshot in your updated question, you can find the answer in this post. Basically the DatatypeConverter class is not part of the JDK Java 9 onwards.

[How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

Comment: Thank you so much for that @steven35. Do you know what specific plugins should I install ?

Comment: Java extension pack is a good place to start. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack

Comment: I already have that extension , but it is still having error.